is ther a good way to read dictionart in the list from a scrapping file so as to be read by views.py file
like this Split result: [{'index': 'PS0191007-001', 'sex': 'M', 'name': 'FNAME LNAME', 'subjects': 'Kisw - B, Eng - B, Maarifa - B, Hisabati - A, Science - B, Grade - B'}]
This came from the scrapping file "
if occurrences:
results = []
for occurrence in occurrences:
parent_tr = occurrence.find_parent('tr')
if parent_tr:
results.append(parent_tr.text.strip())
    parsed_results = []
    for result in results:
        matokeo = re.split(r'\s{2,}', result)
        index = matokeo[0]
        sex = matokeo[1]
        name = matokeo[2]
        subjects = matokeo[3]  # Assuming subjects are already formatted correctly
        parsed_results.append({'index': index, 'sex': sex, 'name': name, 'subjects': subjects})
        print("Split result:", parsed_results)  # Add this line for debugging

        # else:
        #     print("Error: Split result doesn't contain enough elements")  # Add this line for debugging
        #     print("Results:", result)
    return parsed_results

"
it should pass to model and take each data by its own in the result templates
the scrapped data to be resenterd in the table form at the result templates so as to be inthe separate like this "index: ps022013/001
sex: M
name: fname lname
subjects:'Kisw - B, Engl - B, Maarifa - B, Hisabati - A, Science - B, Average Grade - B'
